# Jquery hasClass implementation

Tags: jquery

I am checking for the presence of a class in table tr elements like: 
`<tr class="row1 head4"></tr>`

by the statement: 
`if (that.next().hasClass('.head'+nextRow)){}
 else if (that.next().hasClass('.head'+(nextRow+1))){}`

`nextRow` has values ranging from 1 to 5. but it isnt working. is the syntax wrong?

Comment: `.head` should be `head`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a fullstop prepending class name.  The full stop is only required when using a "normal" jquery selector.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if is what you want but, you can iterate on tr:

```
<table>
    <tr class="row1"><td></td></tr>
    <tr class="row2 head1"><td></td></tr>
    <tr class="row3"><td></td></tr>
    <tr class="row4 head3"><td></td></tr>
</table>



$('table tr').each(function(i){
    if($(this).hasClass('head'+i)) alert($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

See [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/CuNzD/).